# Springloops and commits

Tags: svn, github, tortoisesvn, springloops

My team is using SpringLoops for a website project. And I have my very own springloops account. I have installed Tortoise SVN on my computer so that I can contribute to the project. When I make changes on my local computer and click svn commit, it gets updated on springloops, however there are no changes on the website, Do I have to deploy it on the website? I am not really sure how to test the changes I make on my computer and commit via Tortoise svn, to check for live changes.

Please direct me.

Answer (score 2):

it's late but maybe that will be help someone else,

You should deploy your changes before that they can be displayed in your website (click on "deploy now" on the right of your commit).

If you don't have yet at least one deployment server in your Springloops project you need to add one : "Your Project" > Deployments > Add a new server...
and define your FTP information, you can also make the deployment automatic or manual